# Changing the value and background color of commandButton upon oncomplete

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new to prime faces and I was wondering if there is a way I can change both the value and background colour of a command button upon oncomplete of a method in the backing bean. As of now I still can't think of a way to do both simultaneously. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can call JavaScript function to change the color of button

```
<p:commandButton value="click" id="btn1" actionListener="#{something}"  preocess="@this" oncomplete="changeColor()" />

<script>

function changeColor(){
document.getElementById('btn1').style.background='red';
}

</script>
```